# i want to display my input and the textbox will be remove at the same time in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to display the inputted text only after submitting. textbox will not be visible.

```
            <head><title>some title</title></head>
            <body>
            <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" name="something" value="<?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {echo ($_POST['something']);}?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" />
            </form>
            </body>
            <html>
```

Comment: And .......How did u try it??

Comment: See this: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/240512-showhide-values-in-input-text-box/

Comment: after submitting i want to display only the text the textbox is not visible. what should i use?

Comment: You already have an if-statement. Use the same statement and just echo the value if it is set and the input-field if it isn't?  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. Since I understand now what you've tried, here is the code for what you're actually trying:

```
<body>
    <form name="expense_report" method="POST">
        <div align=center id="submitButtonDiv" >
            <table border=1>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {echo $_POST['txtDate1'];}else {echo '<input type="text" name="txtDate1" size="7" id="datepicker" maxlength="20">';}?></td>
                    <td><?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {echo $_POST['txtOR1'];}else{echo '<input type="text" name="txtOR1" size="15" maxlength="20">';}?></td>
                    <td><?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {echo $_POST['txtTin1'];}else{ echo '<input type="text" name="txtTin1" size="15" maxlength="20">';}?></td>
                    <td><?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {echo $_POST['txtPart1'];}else{ echo '<input type="text" name="txtPart1" size="50" maxlength="80">';}?></td>
                    <td align=right><?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {echo $_POST['txtAmt1'];}else{ echo '<input type="text" name="txtAmt1" size="12" maxlength="20" onChange="add_amount(this.form)">';}?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <?php
        if(empty($_POST['submit'])) {
            echo'
            <div align=center id="progressBar" style="display:block">
                <input type="submit" name="submit"  />
                <input type=reset>
            </div>';
        }
        ?>
    </form>
</body>
```

I tested it, it works. Well, I removed the Javascript part, but since there wasn't anything necessary in it (you can do everything with plain PHP) I think its fine.

Please note that you can't have a `onSubmit` function and a `action=""` at the same time. As you see, I removed the `onSubmit` and also the `action=""` since its posting to the page itself. If you want to post the data to another script, simply add `action="link_to_script.php"` acation in the form header.

If you've still any questions or something doesn't work, feel free to ask. :)

Comment: but i still need onsbumit because i will add a function where it will automatically add my number. it will not work?

Comment: What do you mean with "add my number" ?

Comment: as in addition in math

Comment: OMG! i have so many questions. But I dont know how to say it for you to fully understand me haha

Comment: Where are you from? May we can talk in another language than english, if that would help.

Comment: hi @twinfriends I need a function where it automatically add after inputting some numbers and also like a datepicker for date fields. But as you said I cant have a onsubmit and action="" at the same time? what do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You nearly achieved it by yourself... You have your Control-Structure, so I'm not that sure if you wrote the code by yourself since if you were able to do this till now, you should also be able to find a solution for your problem. Anyway, as mentioned, simply use an IF-Else Statement and only print the whole form if submit isn't set.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        echo $_POST["something"];
    }
    else {
        echo'
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="something">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Send">
        </form>';
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually i did that. I'm doing that in form. which is more complicated. i just create a simple example. but tnak you any way you nearly helped me :)

Comment: <td><?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {echo $_POST['txtDate1'];}else {echo "<input type=text name=txtDate1 size=7 id=datepicker maxlength=20>";}?></td> this is not working on my form

Comment: Its not working because your input field has syntax errors. You wrote `<input type=text name=txtDate1` and so on, but thats not the right HTML syntax. It need to be in `"` - mean: `echo' <input type="text" name="txtDate1" size="7" id="datepicker" maxlength="20">';`

Comment: @saharabanana what do you mean with "can you check this"?  What should I check? In my comment above I just wrote you the code you need to replace so that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function onSubmitButton(){ 
  document.getElementById('submitButtonDiv').style.display = "block"; 
  document.getElementById('progressBar').style.display = "none"; 
  return false; 
}
</script> 
<body>
<form name="expense_report" method="POST" onSubmit="return onSubmitButton()" action="sample.php">
<div align=center id="submitButtonDiv" >
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td><?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {echo $_POST['txtDate1'];}else {echo '<input type="text" name="txtDate1" size="7" id="datepicker" maxlength="20">';}?></td>
<td><?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {echo $_POST['txtOR1'];}else{echo '<input type="text" name="txtOR1" size="15" maxlength="20">';}?></td>
<td><?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {echo $_POST['txtTin1'];}else{ echo '<input type="text" name="txtTin1" size="15" maxlength="20">';}?></td>
<td><?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {echo $_POST['txtPart1'];}else{ echo '<input type="text" name="txtPart1" size="50" maxlength="80">';}?></td>
<td align=right><?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {echo $_POST['txtAmt1'];}else{ echo '<input type="text" name="txtAmt1" size="12" maxlength="20" onChange="add_amount(this.form)">';}?></td>
</tr></table>
</div>
<div align=center id="progressBar" style="display:block">
<input type="submit" name="submit"  />
<input type=reset>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Twinfriends can you check this?

Comment: And whats exactly not working? Can you be a bit more precise pelase... Tell me whats wrong. Do you get a error message? Blank page? What exactly happens? I'm really looking forward to help you, but I need more informations :)

Comment: There is no error. but what i want is an ouput that does not display the text box after user input and clicking the submit button. my code that i post is still displaying the text box

Comment: Ahhh now I totally understand you! :D Well, look: PHP is a server-side language. The script is executed when the page loads, after that it can't be executed anymore until a new reload. Since you submit your form trough javascript, your page is not reloading - means that your IF-statement is never gonna be true. Two ways: Either you remove the fields with javascript too, like you remove the submit button - or you remove the submit button and all those things with PHP too. Give me some minutes, I'll post a solution in a few seconds.